# How to formulate new DataFrame's form a given dataFrame for feature selection in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

My Initial DataFrame Looks like given below(just for example, though it contains different values with more number of inputs)

```
close
1 
2 
3 
4
5
6
```

Now I need to select hyper parameter and based on that I need to create new DataFrames every time.
Suppose my N starts with N=1
then the new dataFrame should look like

```
x1 Y
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

and it will continue till the length of the original dataFrame. Once it done it will move to the next hyperparameter with N=2 and then my new dataFrame should look like

```
X1 X2 Y
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  5
4  5  6
```

and soon, it will continue till certain hyper parameter N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly. This example will create new dataframe from `df['close']` based on the `N`:

```py
N = 1

df_new = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{f"X{i+1}": df["close"].shift(-i)[: len(df) - N] for i in range(N)},
        "Y": df["close"].shift(-N)[: len(df) - N],
    }
).astype(int)
print(df_new)
```

Prints:

```
   X1  Y
0   1  2
1   2  3
2   3  4
3   4  5
4   5  6
```

---

for `N = 2`:

```
   X1  X2  Y
0   1   2  3
1   2   3  4
2   3   4  5
3   4   5  6
```

Comment: Super @Andrej that's great , I just need to restructure the function , it works fine.

Comment: I am unable to make it dynamic, everytime I need to give the N value manually, I tried many ways but it's not happening. I am trying to create a function so that if I call the function with N value as 150 it should give me new 150 dataframes. Open for suggestions